# Powershell if formatting

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach

I'm trying run the below script but when I do I get

> Unexpected token '-PrimaryUserAddress' in expression or statement

How can I fix this?

```
$users = Get-ADUser "joerod" -Properties *|Select-Object SamAccountName, msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress

ForEach ($user in $users) {
if($user.msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress -ne 0){
Write-Host "Removing $($user.samaccountname) from OCS"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parser is hitting that - and interpreting it as a Powershell operator.  Single quote the property so that it gets interpreted as a literal string:

```
if($user.'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress' -ne 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to mjolinor's answer, you could rename the attribute when you select it.

For example, this should work (untested):

```
$users = Get-ADUser "joerod" -Properties *|Select-Object SamAccountName, @{Name="PrimaryUserAddress";Expression={$_."msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress"}}    

ForEach ($user in $users) {
     if($user.PrimaryUserAddress -ne 0){
         Write-Host "Removing $($user.samaccountname) from OCS"
     }
}
```

NB: The 'Name' specifies the new name for the variable, while 'Expression' specifies the variable you wish to rename.